# Elapsed time calculations for data within selected date range

Tags: qlikview

I have data setup as follows:

```
Start Date | End Date 
   A       |       B
```

I want the user to be able to select a date range from a drop down on a sheet, and I need to calculate if A and B (dates from the data) are within the selected date range. If they are, I need to calculate B-A (time elapsed), if not, I need to calculate only the time that elapsed in the selected date range.

Example:

Dates in data: 1/10/2013 to 1/15/2013

User-selected date range: 1/1/2013 to 1/13/2013

I want to calculate the elapsed time as 1/10/2013 to 1/13/2013 (3 days)

What is the best way to do this? I'm new with qlikview, but have php programming experience. Usually I would set the user-selected date range as a variable, and then write a function to calculate the elapsed time based on the data. How is this done in qlikview?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Best,

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with some Set Analysis.

Create a Textbox for example and add the formula:

`=max({$} Date) - min({$} Date)`

The returnd value is the number of days (with fraction).

If you needd that value for further calculations you can add a variable
(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)

Klick insert and name it e.g. selectedtimediff and store

`=max({$} Date) - min({$} Date)`

as definition.

Now you can use *selectedtimediff* in your formulas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Calendar object to do this. Associate the calendar object with a variable and then set the Min Value and Max Value. Then if you select the time out the range, the calendar will set it to the boundary.